# Remove term only if it is on its own line

Tags: php, str-replace

I have this:

```
$text = '
   hello&nbsp;world
   &nbsp;
   &nbsp;hello
';
```

How do I remove `&nbsp;` **only** if it is on its own line? So with above example, the second `&nbsp;` should be removed. Results should be:

```
$text = '
   hello&nbsp;world

   &nbsp;hello
';
```

### What I've tried so far

Via `str_replace()`, I can:

```
$text = str_replace('&nbsp;', '', $text);
```

But that will remove *all* instances of `&nbsp;`, not only when it's on its own line.

Comment: Beautiful addition of _What I've tried so far_ - should be standard on this site. +1

Comment: have you considered using Regular Expressions? They can be told to match things which are the only content on a given line

Comment: Well think about what “being on its own line” actually _means_, technically? That the value has a line break before and after it … so what _could_ you search for now, instead of _just_ `&nbsp;`  …? (Yes, edge cases of it being the first or last line might still need extra handling, but … some basic thinking first of all would not hurt here.)

Comment: @ADyson regex has been an option. But my experience with it is limited.

Comment: @misorude "\n" Ahm "\n" Ahm...

Comment: @misorude Please feel free to post an answer with your approach.

Comment: @OfirBaruch I tried `$text = str_replace('\n'.'&nbsp;'.'\n', '', $text);` but didn't work. [See](https://ideone.com/1MXxIT).

Comment: @Syscall that still won't work, as it contains spaces or tabs.

Comment: @FlashThunder Why don't you post an answer using `str_replace()` instead of judging my experience. =)

Comment: @HenrikPetterson why it has to use str_replace? why not preg_replace?

Comment: @FlashThunder _If_ it is _not_ possible with `str_replace()`, then please feel free to suggest a different approach. My initial route was `str_replace()`.

Comment: Why don't use preg_replace function.
`preg_replace("/&nbsp;\n/", '', $text)`

Comment: @please feel free to upvote + check my answer in case you are happy with my reply :) Thank you and good luck with your project :)

Comment: @misorude But this is something you will need to discuss with the community over at meta if you feel it is a site-wide issue. Why are you pushing it here?

Comment: `'\n'` is not special. It is the two characters `\ ` and `n`. `"\n"` _is_ special. It is a single new line character.

Answer (score 9):

I've already tried this approach and I get the output you want

```
// Your initial text
$text = '
   hello&nbsp;world
   &nbsp;
   &nbsp;hello
';

// Explode the text on each new line and get an array with all lines of the text
$lines = explode("\n", $text);

// Iterrate over all the available lines
foreach($lines as $idx => $line) {
    // Here you are free to do any if statement you want, that helps to filter
    // your text.

    // Make sure that the text doesn't have any spaces before or after and 
    // check if the text in the given line is exactly the same is the &nbsp;
    if ( '&nbsp;' === trim($line) ) {
        // If the text in the given line is &nbsp; then replace this line 
        // with and emty character
        $lines[$idx] = str_replace('&nbsp;', '', $lines[$idx]);
    }
}

// Finally implode all the lines in a new text seperated by new lines.
echo implode("\n", $lines);
```

My output on my local is this:

```
hello&nbsp;world

&nbsp;hello
```

Comment: this will remove whitespaces as well, and author wanted to remove only `&nbsp;`

Comment: @FlashThunder what I have as output is totally aligned with the output has been requested by the question. If you check my output is identical to inital requirement :) Did you try to run my code in PHP 7? Did you got any other output ?

Comment: I would say that author is not even aware that there is a tab/few spaces in there, as he was asking in other comment for space after it (and it doesn't contain that).

Comment: @FlashThunder I am aware. I was just asking for a case example.

Comment: @HenrikPetterson but you wanted those to be removed or not? as you asked for removing `&nbsp;`, so my solution leaves the whitespaces

Comment: @FlashThunder now it maintains also the tabs.

Comment: Yupp, was just a comment. I posted pretty the same solution.

Comment: @FlashThunder did you also downvoted my answer? :) Because I got one and I don't understand why.

Comment: oh sorry had to be a missclick

Comment: @FlashThunder no worries :) Thank you again for mentioning the error ;) :) Have a nice day.

Answer (score 2):

My approach would be:

1. Explode text on new lines
2. Trim each value in the array
3. Empty each array item with value `&nbsp;`
4. Implode with new lines

Resulting in the following code:

```
$chunks = explode(PHP_EOL, $text);
$chunks = array_map('trim', $chunks);
foreach (array_keys($chunks, '&nbsp;') as $key) {
    $chunks[$key] = '';
}
$text = implode(PHP_EOL, $chunks);
```

Comment: The output of your code is not identical to what is asked :/

```
hello&nbsp;world
&nbsp;hello
```

The initial requirement is to only replace the `&nbsp;` with empty text, without remote the whole line :/. Also, keep in mind is not me that downvoted your answer :) My comment was just a friendly message :)

Comment: Way much better now :)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like this:

```
$text = preg_replace("~(^[\s]?|[\n\r][\s]?)(&nbsp;)([\s]?[\n\r|$])~s","$1$3",$text);
```

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f4192b95e0e41833b09598b6ec1258dca93c7f06

(that works on **PHP5**, but somehow doesn't work on some versions of **PHP7**)

---

Alternative would be:

```
<?php
    $lines = explode("\n",$text);
    foreach($lines as $n => $l)
        if(trim($l) == '&nbsp;')
            $lines[$n] = str_replace('&nbsp;','',$l);
    $text = implode("\n",$lines);
?>
```

Comment: I test it and doesn't work :) . Also keep in mind I didn't give you any downvotes. That's just a friendly comment :) The output remains unchanged after testing your solution.

Comment: @MerianosNikos how doesn't it?? http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f4192b95e0e41833b09598b6ec1258dca93c7f06

Comment: That's what I get in my local when I run your code: https://pasteboard.co/IUkf2MK.png :)

Comment: @MerianosNikos oh funny, works on PHP5 but doesn't work on PHP7.

Comment: @MerianosNikos did I just find a PHP7 bug? Hmm... really weird, should work.

Comment: Anyway I upvoted you when you realized the issue :) xaxaxaxa

Comment: @B001ᛦ so has to be a bug of 7.(?)

Answer (score 1):

If you know your end of line chars, and your `&nbsp;` is always followed by a new line:

```
<?php
$text = '
   hello&nbsp;world
   &nbsp;
   &nbsp;hello
';


print str_replace("&nbsp;\n", "\n", $text);
```

Output (some intial whitespace lost in the formatting here):

```
   hello&nbsp;world

   &nbsp;hello
```

Caveat: Any line that ends with a `&nbsp;` with other content preceeding would also be affected, so this may not meet your needs.

Comment: This is actually a very solid solution if we stick with `str_replace()`!

Comment: @Progrock is it possible to adjust it in a way where it takes count for spaces after `&nbsp;`? For example: `"&nbsp;  \n"`

Comment: @HenrikPetterson no

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regular expression for this, using the DOTALL and MULTILINE modifiers together with look-around assertions:

```
preg_replace("~(?sm)(?<=\n)\s*&nbsp;(?=\n)~", '',$text);
```

- `(?sm)`: DOTALL (s) MULTILINE (m)
- `(?<=\n)`: preceeding newline (not part of the match)
- `\s*&nbsp;\s*`: single &nbsp; with optional surrounding whitespace
- `(?=\n)`: trailing newline (not part of the match)

```
>>> $text = '                                                                                               
 hello&nbsp;world                                                                                         
 &nbsp;                                                                                                   
 &nbsp;hello                                                                                           
 ';
=> """
   \n
      hello&nbsp;world\n
      &nbsp;\n
      &nbsp;hello\n
   """
>>> preg_replace("~(?sm)(?<=\n)\s*&nbsp;\s*(?=\n)~", '',$text);
=> """
   \n
      hello&nbsp;world\n
   \n
      &nbsp;hello\n
   """
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could split into lines then substitute `&nbsp;` for the empty string on lines that only contain a `&nbsp;` and whitespace.

We'll keep the original line endings, by capturing them.

```
<?php

$text = '
   hello&nbsp;world
   &nbsp;
   &nbsp;hello
';
$lines = preg_split('@(\R)@', $text, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
foreach($lines as &$v)
    if (trim($v) === '&nbsp;')
        $v = str_replace('&nbsp;', '', $v);

$result = implode($lines);
var_dump($result);
```

Output:

```
string(40) "
   hello&nbsp;world

   &nbsp;hello
"
```